# what does the fc.$error do in AngularJS formly?

Tags: angularjs, angular-formly

I am learning how to use angular js formly, and saw this example about required field. http://angular-formly.com/#/example/other/toggle-required

But I don't really understand `ng-messages="fc.$error"` here. Why it is `fc.$error`? where does the fc come from? I changed the `fc` to any other name, then it stops working....

so confused, anyone could explain?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fc` is a shortcut for `options.formControl`. See [the docs](http://docs.angular-formly.com/v6.13.0/docs/field-configuration-object#formcontrol-ngmodelcontroller). The `formControl` is the field's instance of the [`NgModelController`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController) which is where [`$error`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$error) comes from (and that's what [ngMessages](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMessages) is expecting). This is why passing anything else to it stops working.